# Same app for iphone and ipad but not Universal?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have developed an application for the iPhone devices and I want to also write it for iPad devices. I do NOT want to create a Universal App. I want each type to be treated as a different app in the appstore.

I am using xcode 4

Can anyone guide me to a good doc/tutorial as I didn't find much on this issue.

should I create a new project ? Can I use the existing code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a new target in your existing project and change its target device.

I suggest ensuring that all your build settings (except for target device) are set at the project, not target, level. You'll have to ensure that you include all resources and code in both targets.

Comment: do you have any Link for more clarification...?? Acc. to ur answer means i can use same Bundle ID for iphone and iPad app (both different projects)..?

Comment: You'll need different bundle ids for your two apps.